# How to convert postgresql ARRAY_AGG data to Java Set

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to get some data that is ARRAY_AGG() in a native SQL query:

```
ARRAY_AGG(table.foo) as foos
```

(There's a GROUP BY in the query, so it needs to be ARRAY_AGG to get the results into a single array type column value.)

And it needs to convert to a Java Set:

```
Set<Long> foos;
```

in my POJO class.

Doesn't have to use ARRAY_AGG, if there's another way.

Right now, I'm getting an exception when I call:

```
this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
```

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
```

Any way to avoid that exception and get the data converted?

Comment: Well, I don't have something that converts it to a Set, but I can get you an array if you're using Hibernate 5.2. I have yet to test it with 5.3. Just add this dependency http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor/1.0 and have your column be saved as an array of strings or whatever.

Comment: does it work with hibernate 4.3? If so, what do I need to add to my code to use it? Or is it automatic?

Comment: No. It doesn't even sork with 5.1 or 5.0. It needs 5.2

Comment: ok, thanks, unfortunately we're stuck with 4.x for now

Comment: Without the obfuscation layer it would be as easy as calling`ResultSet.getArray().getArray()` to retrieve the array from the result set

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry, not following...which obfuscation layer? are you suggesting an alternate layer to make the call at (perhaps bypassing hibernate)?

Comment: "ORM" == "Obfuscated Relational Model" - obfuscation layer. Yes, I am talking about "plain" JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you're stuck with an old version, then a possible solution would be using a custom parser and these annotations.

```
@Transient
private Set<String> aggs;

@Column(name = "the_agg_column")
private String raw;

@PostLoad
protected void readAgg() {
Set<String> s = new TreeSet<>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean isquoted = false;
final int len = raw.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    char c = raw.charAt(i);
    if (c == '"') {
        if (sb.length() == 0) isquoted = true;
        else if (isquoted) isquoted = false;
        continue;
    }
    if (c == ',' || c == '}') {
          // do finish-up
          s.add(sb.toString());
          sb.setLength(0);
          continue;
    }
    if (isquoted && c == '\\') {
        c = raw.charAt(++i);
    }
    sb.append(c);
}
```

This basically tells Hibernate that you want to fetch it in String format, so then you have to parse the Postgres array string format.

The escape character handling could probably do with some special cases, but I'm betting you're using an Enum, which is why I went with a Set (or better would be EnumSet).

If you do expect potentially needing to escape characters other than `"` or `\`, this will help you https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-BACKSLASH-TABLE

Comment: actually, the data is longs/bigints

Comment: It's failing at entityManager.getResultList() though, so I don't know that postload will help?